# Confusion on ServerSocket(port)

Tags: java

I have a little confusion on one of the constructor of ServerSocket.
When i write `ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(3000);`,does it mean that i have requested a Connection
on port number 3000 of **server**.

Answer (score 3):

No, this means that your process will *listen* on port 3000 for incoming connections. This means that, provided you follow all the necessary steps in your server code, a client would be able to connect to the server on port 3000 and talk to your application.

Take a look at the following tutorial for an introduction to sockets programming in Java: [Lesson: All About Sockets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/).

Comment: Will listen on port 3000 for incoming connections.

Comment: @ aix what is meant by "for incoming connections."?

Comment: @ aix that is what i have written in my question.So the port number 3000 is of server

Comment: actually accept() also needs to be called to fulfill your description.

Answer (score 1):

This means that your server will be **bound** to port 3000.  To have your server socket **listen** for incoming connections, on port 3000, do:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(3000);
Socket connection = ss.accept();
```

Calling `ss.accept()` causes the server socket to wait and listen for incoming connections on the port it was bound to.  The `Socket` returned from `ss.accept()` is what you will use to communicate with the client that has connected to your server.

Comment: to do a bit more nitpicking, it will be bound to port 3000 of all local network interfaces :-)